# How to setup 2 django virtual environment in 1 apache server

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

Environment:
Apache: 2.4
Python 3.7.2 (32bit)
1st Django: 2.1.15
2nd Django: 3.2.11
System: Windows Server 2016
Database: SQL Server 2016

I'm a newcomer in Apache and I want to add a new Django project (3.2.11) on an Apache server, which has been served an other Django project (2.1.15) for a long time. After checking some tutorial on the internet, I still can let only one Django project available, below are my configurations:

file: httpd.conf
Listen *:1111
Listen *:2222
active LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
active Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

file: httpd-vhosts.conf

```
LoadFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "d:/django_project1/env1/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win32.pyd"

WSGIPythonHome "d:/django_project1/env1/"
#WSGIPythonHome "d:/django_project2/env2/"  <- I can't active both WSGIPythonHome at same time.

<VirtualHost *:1111>
    ServerName http://10.198.170.91
    ServerAlias http://10.198.170.91
    WSGIScriptAlias / D:/django_project1/web_project/web_project/wsgi_windows.py

    <Directory D:/django_project1/web_project/web_project>
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static D:/django_project1/web_project/apps/static
    <Directory D:/django_project1/web_project/apps/static\>
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot "D:/django_project1/web_project"
    <Directory "D:/django_project1/web_project">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/django_project1-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/django_project1-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:2222>
    ServerName http://10.198.170.91
    ServerAlias http://10.198.170.91
    WSGIScriptAlias / D:/django_project2/web_project/web_project/wsgi_windows.py

    <Directory D:/django_project2/web_project/web_project>
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static D:/django_project2/web_project/apps/static
    <Directory D:/django_project2/web_project/apps/static\>
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot "D:/django_project2/web_project"
    <Directory "D:/django_project2/web_project">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/django_project2-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/django_project2-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

django_project1's wsgi_windows.py:

```
import os
import sys
import site
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

site.addsitedir("D:/django_project1/env1/Lib/site-packages")

sys.path.append('D:/django_project1/web_project') 
sys.path.append('D:/django_project1/web_project/web_project')  

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'web_project.settings' 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "web_project.settings")  
 
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

django_project2's wsgi_windows.py:

```
import os
import sys
import site
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

site.addsitedir("D:/django_project2/env2/Lib/site-packages")

sys.path.append('D:/django_project2/web_project') 
sys.path.append('D:/django_project2/web_project/web_project')  

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'web_project.settings' 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "web_project.settings")  
 
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I found that if I active `WSGIPythonHome "d:/django_project1/env1/"`, 1st Django project's website (http://10.198.170.91:1111) is available but 2nd Django project isn't, if I active `WSGIPythonHome "d:/django_project2/env2/"`, 2nd Django project's website (http://10.198.170.91:2222)  is available but 1st Django project isn't

If I active both `WSGIPythonHome "d:/django_project1/env1/"` and `WSGIPythonHome "d:/django_project2/env2/"`, apache service can't start normally.

I have tried many ways but Apache server seen that can't setup 2 WSGIPythonHome at same time, I'm going crazy, can somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, Apache mod_wsgi can only handle one env for both vurtual hosts. If you absolutely can not share one, you can setup the env inside the wsgi.py files. First pls make sure you really need seperate env.

Comment: @Razenstein thank you for the advice, I will try to setup env inside the wsgi.py.